# It is possible to insert data using views by using order by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view

During my interview for the position of SQL Developer the interviewer asked me one question

> It is possible to insert data using views including order by clause?

I answered to the interviewer "No it is not possible". But she told that it is possible. I searched through internet but I couldn't get the solution.

So, kindly give me the solution.

Comment: The question is poorly worded - personally I would call it nonsense. The "order by clause" reference is not clear since it might apply to the view definition or it might apply to the insert statement (using a select query as the row source). Your response should have been to ask for clarification. A follow-up question about proof would also be appropriate. Sounds like a trick question involving a very special situation - at best. But lots of "senior" people have some fundamental misconceptions about sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create the view with `order by` (unless some limit clause is used) but you can use the `order by` when selecting from view and insert into table using the `insert into .. select .. order by ..`

```
insert into test(t_col)
select vw_col from vw order by vw_col
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=247e4f92b43d33cef98030f1cf001d09) example

Answer (score 0):

If you are phrasing the question correctly, I would say you are correct for the following reasons:

1. Views do only allow `order by` clauses except with very limited exceptions.
2. Views can be arbitrary queries, and hence most views are not "insertable" (the real term is *updatable*).

There are specific exceptions to each of these.  For instance, you can use `select top 100 percent` in a view that has a query  with an `order by`.  However, that doesn't mean that the view is "ordered".  Simply that the top 100% of rows based on the `order by` are returned.

Similarly, there are some views that are insertable.  In general, though, you would need to write an `insert` trigger on a view to insert into it.

Hmmm . . . I guess the answer might be "yes", but only under very limited and specific circumstances.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f87e849a5461b7768c374491b24a4c8c) is an example where it actually works.  But to be honest, I think "no" illustrates better knowledge of SQL Server unless you are answering an essay question.